# Change color frame selected image Indesign CC 2019

Tags: adobe-indesign, color

Anyone who knows how to change the color of the frame from a selected image in Indesign?
Seems some files have a yellow frame when I try to select the image inside a box. The yellow frame is to hard to see on a blank background.
In some other files it's a cyan frame instead of yellow.

I wanted to change it to a color I can see better than yellow.
Seems no option to change it inside Indesign preferences. Also has nothing to do with the layers I'm working with.

Can I change it? How does it happen to be yellow or cyan?

[image: screenshot yellow frame]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `graphic frame` color comes from the layer color.
2. **The graphic border color is the `graphic frame` color inverted**.

Answer (score 1):

Explained in more dummy-detail: The layer you're working in has a color. The border around an image (graphic frame) will get this color. The border around a selected image inside the frame is the inverted color of this layer. So if you have set the layer on black, the border of a selected image becomes white and will be difficult to see.

You can change this by changing the color of the layer: Open the layer panel double clicking on the layer you're currently working on to open layer options. Change color to purple. The selected images frame becomes green.